# org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.text.ResourceTransferDragAdapter is missing

Tags: eclipse-plugin

org.eclipse.search.internal.ui.text.ResourceTransferDragAdapter is missing on jar org.eclipse.search (version-3.7.0).Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: You shouldn't be using/relying on an internal API class.

Comment: So we need to create our own class or eclipse providing an alternative for this one?

Answer (score 0):

Classes with `internal` in the package are internal use only classes and are not part of the Eclipse API see [Eclipse API Rules of Engagement](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-API-Use/index.html). Since they are not part of the API internal classes are subject to change or removal without notice. This particular class appears to have been removed round about release 3.4.

The class is actually very small and does not have any dependencies on other internal classes, so you could copy the old source to somewhere in your plugin and use that.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the reply